# Can't get div to go on the bottom of the page, CSS, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the div to the bottom of the page but it's not working the way I want it to work for some reason. I've set the position of the div to relative, and the bottom to 0, but the thing is that if there are no text in between the div, the div doesn't go to the bottom. I need to div to be at the bottom when there are text in between and when there aren't text in between. How do I do that? Thanks.

```
div {
border: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
bottom: 0px;
}

<?php

while($num < 100) {
echo "Stuff<br>";
$num++;
}

?>
<div> Div </div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If jQuery is an option you can do this.

```
(function($){
    if($('div').is(':empty')) {
     $('div').removeClass("bottom"); 
    }
    else{
     $('div').addClass("bottom");  
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Here is a link. I made a small change to the CSS to the width as well.

You will need to use position absolute as stated by Lund.

http://jsfiddle.net/JrodR87/apj4m4en/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: What does the javascript say?

Comment: if div is empty, remove class bottom to do css to bring div to top.

else add the class bottom, which will move the div to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `bottom: 0px;` position has to be absolute.

Comment: Or `position : fixed`

Comment: If I put position is absolute when there are more text then the page height it doesn't go to the bottom. It gets stuck in the middle of the texts.

Comment: I assume that, if I understand everthing like you meant it, that you will need to make use of some wrapper div.

Comment: So you know how to fix it or not?